# Count and percentage with Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I currently have three sets of columns:

1. Several columns with values of either true or false to indicate if a certain action has taken place.
2. "Helper" columns which interpret TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0 for the columns in #1. This column is displayed as a SUM value and is grouped by 1 level.
3. TOTAL column which displays the total number of records. This is a value column which uses a COUNT on the record title.

A sample table demonstrating the layout is below.

Is there a way to display the count of an individual as a percentage of the count?

```
            TOTAL Action1 Action2 Action3
Group  1    3     3       0       1
 Record 1A  1     1       0       0
 Record 1B  1     1       0       0
 Record 1C  1     1       0       1

Group  2    3     2       2       1
 Record 2A  1     0       1       0
 Record 2B  1     1       1       0
 Record 2C  1     1       0       1
```

**Question**
My end goal is to display the number of TRUEs for each action as both a SUM for the group (already done) and percentage of the group TOTAL. How would you create a column that displays for example Action1 SUM as a percentage of TOTAL count?

Comment: In your example, the helper column, is that actually the row "group1"? What do you mean with individual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a new column with the following formula:

> `= (`*`CELL`*`/`*`CELL`*`) * 100`

So if the cell [Group 1 * TOTAL] is B2 and the cell [Group 1 * Action 1] is C2, then the formula should be:

```
=(C2/B2)*100
```

Comment: Or just compute `C2/B2` and format it as a percentage.

Comment: @Scott's suggestion is better. Manually multiplying a value by 100 can cause unexpected results later.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add (drag) your `action` column a second time into the `Values` section of the field list
2. Change this field to `Show Values As` = `% of Parent Row Total`

This will result in:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!  Change Show Value As is found by right clicking on the field in the VALUE pane and selecting, Value Field Settings

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.